# Cascading managed metadata columns

Tags: managed-metadata, filter, term-store, cascading

I have set up the following terms hierarchy in the Term Store:

- My Terms

  - Departments

    - Accounting

      - Project Accounting
      - Procurement
    - Human Resources

      - Payroll
      - Recruiting

I have then created two columns:

- Department - managed metadata column bound to Departments term set
- Category - managed metadata column also bound to Departments term set

What I would like to do is when I create a new list item, I want to choose a Department and have only "Accounting" and "Human Resources" as available options; and then have the choices in "Category" matching the children of selected department.

Is that possible without coding?

Comment: You have to implement the jsLink or the list/library to show the managed metadata column as cascaded dropdowns.